# Удаленный проект Netbeans + .gdbinit

Tags: centos, netbeans, отладка, gdb

Добрый день!

Возникла проблема с отладкой удаленного проекта. Запускаю Netbeans под Win7x64, создаю удаленный проект с исходными кодами на удаленной машине Linux (CentOS6 x86_64). Собираю проект и запускаю на исполнение, подключаюсь отладчиком - все работает отлично, за исключением того, что отладчик периодически зависает, отваливается с ошибками, работает не устойчиво. Версия отладчика gdb довольно старая.

Обновляю (ставлю из исходников) последнюю версию gdb - все работает быстро, ничего не отваливается, но отладчик не видит сущности из STL (итераторы, map и т.д.).

Прописываю в .gdbinit как это рекомендуют:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gdb/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

Но ничего не происходит, как будто бы он (.gdbinit ) вообще не используется. Может быть, кто ни будь, сталкивался с подобными проблемами как их решить? Что бы отладчик увидел сущности STL.

P.S. Запуск на удаленной машине  происходит сл. Образом (ps aux | grep gdb):

```
root     28094  0.0  0.0   3932   392 ?        Ss   14:45   0:00 /var/tmp/dlight_root/3f6507a2/01514253146/pty --dir /usr/local/ --no-pty --readenv /var/tmp/dlight_root/3f6507a2/env /usr/local/bin/gdb -x C:\Users\user/.gdbinit --interpreter mi
root     28103  0.0  0.0   3932   404 ?        Ss   14:45   0:00 /var/tmp/dlight_root/3f6507a2/01514253146/pty --dir /usr/local/ --no-pty -- /var/tmp/dlight_root/3f6507a2/env /usr/local/bin/gdb -x C:\Users\user/.gdbinit --interpreter mi
root     28104  7.1  9.5 324544 184448 ?       Ss   14:45   0:02 /usr/local/bin/gdb -x C:\Users\user/.gdbinit --interpreter mi
```

Возможно отладчик пытается найти путь "C:\Users\user/.gdbinit" на удаленной машине? но ошибок ни каких не наблюдается.